# iPhone: fast hash function for storing web images (url) as files (hashed filenames)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, hash, md5

What is a fast hash function available for the iPhone to hash web urls (images)?

I'd like to store the cached web image as a file with a hash as the filename, because I suppose the raw web url could contain strange characters that could cause problems on the file system.

The hash function doesn't need to be cryptographic, but it definitely needs to be fast.

**Example:**

Input: `http://www.calumetphoto.com/files/iccprofiles/icc-test-image.jpg`

Output: `3573ed9c4d3a5b093355b2d8a1468509`

This was done by using MD5(), but since I don't know much about that topic I don't know if it is overkill (-> slow).

Comment: Well since you'll be writing the file to a file system, pretty much any hashing algorithm will be more than fast enough.  Personally, I'd just go for replacing the / characters with percent escapes.

Comment: JeremyP: That may make the pathname too long for a filename.

Comment: @JeremyP: well, in the most cases I will be loading from the file system. But you're right. That's still way more expensive than the hashing.

Comment: @Peter:  +1 that's a good point.  Just googled HFS+ and the limit is only 255 characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MD5 may be broken for security purposes, but it works well for the situation you describe. [Here's a thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7362074) on how to implement it on iPhone. Check out Vroomtrap's post. For posterity, here's my own version of that code:

```
- (NSString *)MD5Hash {
    const char *cStr = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );

    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11], result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15] ];
}
```

You'll need to import the `CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h` header.

Comment: I found this one here very helpful: http://www.saobart.com/md5-has-in-objective-c/

Comment: I'd recommend using `dataUsingEncoding:` instead of `UTF8String`. `strlen` is not cheap, since it has to walk the entire string to find the end of it to know how long it is. The NSData object knows how long the data is.

Comment: You're welsome to do so. My empirical testing showed that using dataUsingEncoding performed the same as the above method on strings of moderate length (200K) and substantially worse on large strings (2M).

Answer (score 0):

I think the NSObject already has a hash function. And NSUrl or NSString can override it, can you try with those things. I think in most of cases, it is fast enough, like we put NSString into NSDictionary:)
[NSObject hash](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash)

Comment: As a return value I get an Integer value, which I can convert to a string and use it as a filename. However, is that "strong" enough to differentiate between the many different urls out there? How likely is it that two different urls result in the same hash?

Comment: I can not find any documents on google for that :(. But I think if you have a small number of urls (10 - 100, I just guessed), it can be ok. But I found out that usually people use MD5 to generate the hash, so performance may not be a big problem with MD5

Comment: Thanks. I actually checked the time to execute both, and MD5 is pretty much the same as [myObject hash]

Comment: You should generally not use this for storing files as collisions are somewhat common with NSObject's -hash function. Apple doesn't make any guarantees about collisions with this method, and I introduced a severe crash using it for image cache hashing once.

Comment: @TimJohnsen What did you end up using as a hash function to generate filenames?

Comment: I generally use MD5