# Converting URL into some other form of string

Tags: objective-c, dns

I want to ask is there anyway I can convert my URL into some other string?

Example:
Let say given 
www.stackoverflow.com

I wanna convert it into some other not so readable URL,
www.1231222.com << just an example

So later on, when I read this URL (www.1231222.com) it will convert back to www.stackoverflow.com

**Or is it possible to shorten the URL and recover it back later?**

Does this consider as encoding?

Comment: You could try a MD5Hash:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934919/iphone-fast-hash-function-for-storing-web-images-url-as-files-hashed-filenam][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934919/iphone-fast-hash-function-for-storing-web-images-url-as-files-hashed-filenam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other words... Is there any browser HTTP compatible encoding able to obfuscate a URL? yes, you can replace the domain with the equivalent IP and express that IP as hex, dword, or octal encoding.

Example, here is stackoverflow.com in dword 1076000524, hex 0x40.0x22.0x77.0x0c, and octal 0100.0042.0167.0014. Some websites will throw a 400 (stackoverflow being one) if you access with such names, and others won't (eg: for http://google.com try http://0112.0175.0346.0362).

This lets you obfuscate and still have a working HTTP address. But if you want to reverse the obfuscation you would need to access the IP to get the domain.

I don't know either which is your use case, is this all from an iPhone app? maybe you could store the obfuscated/real domain as a dictionary on your app.