# How to avoid image duplication in image gallery of iOS device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to store the images to photo gallary. But if images are already available at photo gallary then how to distinguish for whether imgaes are already exists or not? I didnt find property like unique identifier or should i compare by taking data in the form of NSdata?

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain a dictionary of hashes for each the image in the photo gallery, and then show only additional images who do not hashes are not present in the dictionary

As a reminder, you can check for an object in a dictionary by doing:

```
if ([myDictionary objectForKey:variableStoringImageHash] == nil) {
   //No such image present
}
else {
   //image is present
}
```

For a bit about hashing an image, this might help:
[iPhone: fast hash function for storing web images (url) as files (hashed filenames)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934919/iphone-fast-hash-function-for-storing-web-images-url-as-files-hashed-filenam)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if what eitan27 says will work so as an alternative I would say that your best hope is comparing NSData objects. But this as you can see will become very tedious as there will be n number of images in library and comparing each one for repetition does't make sense , still if you want to compare data you look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806230/919545) answer which will give you a fraction of how much the data is matching.